# How to dissable/Avoid error "Vuejs Props should at least define their types"?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, eslint, vuetify.js, lint

I am getting eslint warning like " Props should at least define their types?  require-prop-types"

```
<script>

export default {

    props: ['Age', 'Name'],

    created(){
      ....
    },  
    ....

 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the warning

**Solution 1:**

```
 props: {
    Age: {
        type: Number,

    },
    Name: {
      type: String
},
```

To disable warning:

**Solution 2:**

add this rule in .eslintrc.js or  .eslintrc.* or  .eslintrc.json file

```
 .eslintrc.js or  .eslintrc.* or  .eslintrc.json file

 rules: { 
    //....add your existing rules and below line as well
    "vue/require-prop-types":0
 }
```